# How to make new directory to a SD card using a python script

Tags: python, sd-card, mkdir

I need to setup a raspberry pi in a SD CARD. That's why, after writing raspberrypi to SD card, I need to create a directory at /Volumes/boot, named ssh. For that I tried

```
os.mkdir("/Volumes/boot/ssh")
```

But it is showing `/Volumes/boot: No such file or directory` But, in stead of python script, if I write the same command in python3's console, it is working perfectly. I also tried:

```
os.mkdir("/Volumes/boot/ssh")
```

But it is not working too. So, how can I make /Volumes/boot/ssh this folder in my SD card using python script?

Comment: What permissions (i.e. administrative/sudo, user etc.) are you running your script and interactive shell with?

Comment: I haven't added any code to provide admin permission. But, Before running this command, My script runs another command, which includes sudo. There I need to give password too. Besides, does it really matter? Actually, I am new to python. So, don't know much. But, in terminal, I am sure there is no admin privilege, but this mkdir command works perfectly.

Comment: Given you are using an absolute path, the likely issue is permissions (or potentially the SD has been unmounted between running the script and console command).
1. What OS are you using to run the script
2. When you start the console what command do you use (i.e `sudo python3`) and when you run your script what command do you use (i.e. `sudo python my_script.py`)

Comment: Understood. When I start console, I don't use sudo command. Just ```python3``` and same for running script. Just ```python3 my_script.py```